# Problems in installing flash player

Tags: flash

I am facing problems in installing flash player. It had got the package uninstalled while removing other packages. Now, whenever I am trying to install the package flashplugin-installer, I am getting the following error:

```
E: flashplugin-installer: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I have tried installing the package from Adobe website, from the repository, and have also tried installing the adobe-flashplugin.

I keep getting the same error every time.

Comment: have you run `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Yes I have, after completely removing flash player. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no package on the Adobe web site. You download file install_flash_player_11_linux.x86_64.tar.gz, move it to a directory by itself, and extract the contents. The contents will ba a file, libflashplayer.so, and a directory, usr.

You copy the .so file to the plugins directory for whatever browser you are using. On my system, using Firefox, that is /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins

Then, you copy the contents of the usr directory to your system's /usr: "sudo cp -r ./usr/* /usr"

Comment: Thanks Tim. This solved my problem. I was still not able to install the flash player using synaptic, and it did not strike me that I could have manually copied the .so file. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Go and look at this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto#How_to_fix_broken_packages).  If you have a broken package it will hogtie your package manager until you dispatch with the problem.  I have seen this happen with flash player.

Comment: Thanks. But there are no broken dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using SYNAPTIC, a package administrator easy to use.
Download ADOBE F.P. from the website and you can find SYNAPTIC in UBUNTU's Software Center.
Open SYNAPTIC, select FLASH PLAYER and "APPLY".

Comment: could you improve your answer with downloading links and installation process ?